# Linking json-c library to my C project

Tags: c, json, linux

I have a C project. Its source code has many c files and I want to compile them all by using Makefile, also I need to link Curl library and json-c library to this project.

I have copied the `libjson-c.so` from my `/lib/i386-linux-gnu` since i have already installed it before and then past it in my_project "lib" directory, then i have copied json-c folder which include the header files from my `/usr/include` and then paste it into my_project "include" directory.

Then in the "Makefile" I assign the `CFLAGS` to my_project "include" directory and my DLLs assigned to the "Dll" files directory and then I linked the json-c lib by adding `-ljson-c` but when I compile my project it returns:

```
error : "/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -ljson-c
```

Now I'm confused about what's wrong here specially, I have already did the same with the Curl library and it works but now with the json-c it's not. So PLEASE I NEED A HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use -L option to link your program with your library?

I see you use libjson-c which was built on linux-i386 architecture. But in the error, i see the compiler search library in arm folder. Did you use right compiler?

Comment: Well, for the project I'm using "makecore" compiler which is not gcc, So according to your question it seems like it's not allowed, is it?!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file path, e.g. **/myLibDir/libjson-c.so**

Add like this to Makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -L/myLibDir -ljson-c
```